# Exactly align a fixed navbar to a carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added "fixed-top" to the header, but now part of the carousel is behind the navbar.

(a part of the building in the picture is behind the navbar)
[image]

Is there a way in placing them below each other, no overlapping and without adding a manual margin px?

code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  //CONTENT
</nav>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  //CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to set nav display as block?

Comment: .navbar {
  display: block;
} (no results)

Comment: "_beside each other_" Beside? Not below?

Comment: below each other, my bad edited it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you achieve what are you looking for.

```
.fixed-top{
  height:48px; //if you are taking height 48px;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.carousel{
  position:relative;
  top:48px; // use top 48px to solve this problem
}
```

Comment: this shoots the fixed navbar up messsing up the header abit